# Issue with two dimensional manipulators

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction

I want to have a dynamic number of manipulators.

```
             n = 4; c = 4;
             With[{  
                    B_controls = Sequence @@ 
                          Table[ {{ B[i, j], 0}, 0, 1, 0.1}, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, c} ]
             },

             Manipulate[
```

Whatever I want to do, and then:

```
                    Control @ B_controls
                    ]
```

But I get the following error:

Manipulate::vsform: Manipulate argument {{{B[1,1],1},0,1,0.1},{{B[2,1],1},0,1,0.1}} does not have the correct form for a variable specification.

Manipulate::vsform: Manipulate argument {{{B[1,2],1},0,1,0.1},{{B[2,2],1},0,1,0.1}} does not have the correct form for a variable specification.

It seems like I'd have to do a simple array of controls, but I'd like to know if I can do it in this way (or if there's a better way).

Thanks!

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: What does the title—"two dimensional manipulators"—have to do with this question?

Comment: I meant it in the sense that the manipulators are a two dimensional matrix.

Comment: First of all, "two-dimensional manipulators" refers to `SLIDER2D`.  I think your title should be "Manipulating the number of controls" or something like that.  Clearer.  Easier for people to find later.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
n = 4; c = 4;
With[{t = Table[b[i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, c}],
  f=Table[{{b[i,j],0},0,1,0.1,ImageSize->Tiny},{i,1,n},{j,1,c}], 
  bControls = 
   Sequence @@ 
    Flatten[ Table[{{b[i, j], 0}, 0, 1, 0.1}, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, c}],1]},

 Manipulate[MatrixForm@t,bControls,TrackedSymbols :> {t}]
 ]
```

Comment: Nasser how did you save the gif with the arrow pointer?

Comment: @Alucard I use program called LICEcap to capture screen to animated gif